# Conducting a comparative analysis with studies that use different response measures

Tags: meta-analysis

I want to conduct a comparative analysis using bird playback studies. Unfortunately, many of these studies use different response measures (closest approach to the speaker, time spent near the speaker, latency to approach the speaker). These studies are still all measuring the same thing (i.e. intensity of bird response to playback stimuli) but go about it using different variables.

Is there a way to compare these studies although they use different response measures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have different measures each with a standard error then you can proceed as usual. You might consider then doing a meta-regression using measure type as a moderator to see whether the response measures you quote are in fact different.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too knowledgeable when it comes to this. Could you clarify what you mean by "proceed as usual." I can't really calculate effect size or anything because there isn't a second group to which I could compare response measures. I'm mostly wondering how to standardize values between the different response measures. I'm guessing there is a way to do this with standard error that I'm not aware of.

Comment: The usual method to which I was referring is to use inverse variance weighting. This is widely available in software in R and Stata as well as in stand-alone packages. I would not recommend trying to do it by hand. I am not sure about your point about not having a comparison group. There is no need for that if all you want to do is to produce a summary estimate.